# When is the MLE equivalent to the MM estimator

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, exponential-family, method-of-moments

I know that in natural exponential families the general method of moments estimator we get from working with the sample and the sufficient statistic [gMM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments) is equivalent to the maximum likelihood estimate we get from maximizing the likelihood of the sample[MLE](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments) (and so we get all sorts of neat aymptotic properties). Do we need more conditions on the distribution of our data (besides that it came from a natural exponential family) so that the method of moments [MM](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_moments_(statistics)) estimator we get from equating sample and population moments is equivalent to the MLE?

Comment: Sure, how's that?

Comment: There is no reason for any gMM or MM to be equal to the MLE. In particular, if you take the MM on a sample from $\mathcal{U}(\theta-1,\theta+1)$, using for instance the empirical mean, the MM will not recover the super-efficiency of the MLE $\{X_{(1)}+X_{(n)}\}/2$.

Comment: Uniform distributions aren't natural exponential families (they're not even exponential families when the uniform has unknown parameters). Further, in a full rank exponential family with natural parameter and sufficient statistic the GMM obtained by equating the sufficient statistic to the mean is exactly the MLE. I'm a little confused by your answer.

Comment: Does your question include the restriction to exponential families???

Comment: It did for the gMM estimate and I imagine a similar condition (plus maybe other conditions) is necessary for the MM. I'll change it to make it clearer.